# Allowed downgrade from v4.8 to v4.5.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have net v4.8 (Visual Studio 2019 and Win10).  I'm unsure if I am allowed downgrade from v4.8 to v4.5.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly install multiple versions of the .net framework SDK and develop solutions that target any one of them. If you are asking if you can uninstall .net framework 4.8 from your Win10 PC, the answer is likely no (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations)